# Windows Server 2k8 RAM Cache Growing, and Growing, and taking up 5GB+

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory

Continuing my adventure of managing a Windows Server 2008 (64-bit, SP2) server for the first time ever, one thing I keep seeing is that the Cache section under Physical Memory in Task Manager continue to grow and grow and grow.

The server is not active yet as I am still loading all the apps, and the only thing it's doing is downloading a 3GB file right now. Still, the cache just keeps growing. The server has 8GB of RAM, and right now the Cache is at 6.3GB...

Is this normal? Should I worry? If it's not normal, what do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry: it is still available for use when needed.  Take a look at the Performance tab in Task Manager, and you'll see the overlap between "Cached" and "Available".

Windows 6.x automatically borrows available memory to enhance disk performance, but the size of the cache is adjusted automatically when memory is needed by applications or services.

Comment: Ahh, I see, although "Available" is not available in the Task Manager of my server (it's a non-R2, if that makes a difference), but I see what you mean by looking at the Windows 7 Task Manager. So, I shouldn't worry about the Cache hogging up everything and the Free section staying at 0MB available then?

Comment: @Alex, if the "Free" is at 0Mb, then the RAM is doing its job - otherwise if the ram was free it would techncially be wasted. may as well have it do stuff while it's not in use by active apps.

Comment: Exactly. Basically Windows caches everyy file it touches - until it finds a better use for the memory. As you do not have a better use.... ;) it goes on caching.